# Put play button image on top of video thumbnail image with text bellow them

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to reproduce this image in html  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeSlp.png)

So that would be 3 videos next to each other with a playbuttom image on top of their thumbnail images and text bellow each of them.I made this with bootstrap and css
Here is my try.

```
<div class="container-fluid grey-box">
                <div class="row pt-5">                   
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 text-center">
                        <div>
                            <div class='video-wrapper'>
                                <div><img class="img-fluid image-border" src="https://i.ibb.co/b58hryQ/EPISTROFES2.png"></div>
                                <div class='video-overlay'>
                                    <img class="play-button2" src="https://i.ibb.co/KNvfBVJ/Playe-Button.png">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h2 class="py-5">ΕΠΙΣΤΡΟΦΕΣ</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and my css

```
  .video-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.image-border {
    border: 4px solid #89cdcc;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;    
}

.image-border:hover {
    border: 4px solid #00837a;
}

.video-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.play-button2 {   
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.play-button2:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The play-button seems to be placed on top of the image video pretty well but the problem is that I cant add the text bellow the images because every time i try to add a the text bellow the images the playbutton stops beeing on top of the image.

Here is what happens when I try to add for example an h2 bellow the 2 images in the code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udy8Q.png)

Comment: can you post more style please?

Comment: Thats all my style

Comment: I can't reproduce your image example. Also, there's an extra `"` at the end of your first `image-fluid effe` src.

Answer (score 3):

```css
 #videos {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
   display: flex;
}

.image-border {
    border: 4px solid #89cdcc;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;    
}

.image-border:hover {
    border: 4px solid #00837a;
}

.video-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 10;
}

.video-background, .video-background .img-fluid{
  height: 300px;
  width: 450px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.video-background{
  position: relative;
}

.play-button2 {   
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: 99;
}

.play-button2:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.py-5{
  text-align: center;
}

.image-border:hover{
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid grey-box">
  <div class="row pt-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 text-center">
      <div id='videos'>
        <div class='video-element'>
          <div class='video-background'>
            <img class="img-fluid image-border" src="https://i.ibb.co/b58hryQ/EPISTROFES2.png">
              <div class='video-overlay'>
            <img class="play-button2" src="https://i.ibb.co/KNvfBVJ/Playe-Button.png">
          </div>
            </div>
          <h2 class="py-5">ΕΠΙΣΤΡΟΦΕΣ</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the play paragraph has to be under the video not under the play button

Comment: Alright, I updated my answer. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: It is prety close yeah but with just one problem,I need when i hover over the video to change the border from red to green but with your code i replaced the empty video and image classes with actuall images and videos but i cant get the hover to work

Comment: And that is when I hover over the image and not the video-overlay

Comment: Does adding `.video-wrapper:hover .video{
  border-color: green;
}` work? i.e. you should add the hover event to the parent element, if the child element is smaller, but you want the effect to occur on the smaller event when the user's mouse enters the bigger parent element

Comment: That is the problemm, i want the effect to accur on the smaller even when the users mouse enters that event not the parent event, the problem is that when I hovering over that event it regognizes i am hover over the parent event and not that one so  it gives the border to the smaller event when i enter the parrent event and that is wrong because sometimes the parent event is much biger that the smaller event and it changes color even when i havent enter the smaller event yet

Comment: Hmm, it's difficult to figure out the issue without seeing your full code. Is your site up? If it is, I could take a look at it...otherwise, it sounds like you need to sort out the sizing of the parent elements. Considering using `display: flex` or `display: grid`

Comment: I am afraid it is not up but i can give you the files if you want, i really need this

Comment: To be honest, I'm also busy. With 7 or 8 personal projects...plus a regular job. And of course personal stuff too. I would have had a quick look at it if your site was up though. Otherwise, I suggest just opening the developer console ("inspect element" in Chrome) and hovering over the elements in the elements tab to see which element is the one that seems to be sized incorrectly. Perhaps you can make another post, sharing more of the problem code so that someone can fix it

Comment: Ok. Can you upload those 2 images to Imgur or something, then update the code so it links them directly? Since I guess for you they're showing, but for us, we just get empty boxes where the images should be...so it's impossible to e.g. know how big things should be

Comment: Alright, I updated my answer. It.......kind of works. Though when the play button is hovered, the video background image hover is lost...

Comment: I think the video-element is not centered inside the bootstrap col, Am I right?

Comment: I am right, it also is not resposive now, if your try to put 3 of them next to each other you will see what I mean, before it did not have that problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221381/discussion-between-stefanie-and-cssproblem).

Comment: I made it centered by puting the class="d-flex justify-content-center" to the< div id="video"> but it is not responsive when you make the window smaller it falls of if you have 3 videos together

Comment: Oh i think the problem was that you put width values to the image

Answer (score 0):

whenever you add text it adds default margin and padding to the block, I assume that might be the one reason for it. Another option you can try creating a new call for text.

Comment: Hi jack , what do you mean a new call? how can i do that?can you please help me?